# Sharing a data set across threads vs. splitting up the data per thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have written a small program that generates images of the Mandelbrot set, and I have been using it as an opportunity to teach myself multithreading.

I currently have four threads that each handle calculating a quarter of the data. When they finish, the data is aggregated to then be drawn to a bitmap.

I'm currently pre-calculating all the complex numbers for each pixel in the main thread and putting them into an vector. Then, I split the vector into four smaller vectors to pass into each thread to modify.

Is there a best practice here? Should I be splitting up my data set so that the threads can work without interfering with eachother, or should I just use one data set and use mutexs/locking? I suppose benchmarking would probably be my best bet.

Thanks, let me know if you'd want to see my code.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is make threads as independent of each other as possible. I'm not familiar with the particular problem you're trying to solve, but if it allows equally dividing work among threads, splitting up the data set will be the most efficient way. When splitting data, have false sharing in mind, and minimize cross-thread data movements.

Choosing other parallelisation strategies makes sense on cases where, e.g.,:

- Eliminating cross-thread dependencies requires a change to the algorithm that will cause too much extra work.
- The amount of work per thread isn't balanced, and you need some dynamic work assignment to ensure all threads are busy until work is completed.
- The algorithm is composed of different stages such that task parallelism is more efficient than data parallelism (namely, each stage is handled by a different thread, and data is pipelined between threads. This makes sense if there are too many dependencies within each stage).

Bear in mind that a mutex/lock means wasted time waiting, as well as possibly non-trivial synchronisation overhead if the mutex is a kernel object. However, correctness comes first: if other options are too difficult to get right, you'll lose more than you'll gain. Finally, always compare your parallel implementation to a sequential one. Due to data movements and dependencies, the sequential implementation often runs faster than the parallel one.